# Generate DKIM to prevent Email Spamming

Tags: email, dkim

I have created DKIM (Domain keys Identified mail) keys for my outgoing emails from online web server. I have added the **public keys** in my DNS as a TXT record. Was wondering where do I place the **private keys** in Cpanel?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, in CPANEL it will generate the DKIM Keys automatically for you. You just have to click the ENABLE button.

You can find the instructions here:https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/68Docs/Authentication

Also DKIM, doesn't prevent spamming, but it can help your Protect others from spoofing your domain if your set up [DMARC Records.](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/dmarc/)

Since you're new to setting up these items, I suggest reading through this guide, it goes over all the aspects of sending email that you need to be aware of.

https://www.zerobounce.net/guide-to-improve-inbox-and-delivery.html

Comment: Thanks Henry,, My issue is quite different here,, My domain registrar is different from my hosting company. Would this affect my DKIM keys.. Should I contact the domain registrar or the hosting company concerning the issue? I noticed this error when I checked Email headers of an email send from my website, the DKIM keys were lacking but DMARC and SPF records were okay.

Comment: The registrar has nothing to do it, most of the time you will set the name servers in your registrar to point to the hosting companies. Once that's done the hosting company DNS takes over.